# Is it a security risk for a signature to be publicly available?

Tags: physical-signature

For once, I'm not talking about digital signatures. I'm talking about good old-fashioned pen and paper signatures.

Should I protect my signature like I protect my passwords? Is it a genuine security risk if my signature is known? Intuitively this doesn't make sense to me because many famous signatures are well-known, and autographs are basically the giving away of signatures (in fact, Wikipedia has had a biography field for the signature of very famous celebrities for a while now).

At the same time signatures have always been considered important facets of your personal security that we were told as kids needed to be unique. They are used to sign off on items as important and expensive as mortgages and houses, and written on the back of debit cards so they can be checked against - therefore, it seems reasonable that a bad actor with access to one could use it to devastating effect.

Do personal signatures still have security value, or are they largely an anachronistic relic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do living politicians protect their readily obtainable signatures from misuse?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207640/how-do-living-politicians-protect-their-readily-obtainable-signatures-from-misus), [Why are hand-written signatures still so commonly used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/why-are-hand-written-signatures-still-so-commonly-used).

Comment: Yes, those questions look like they probably will answer my question. I would have thought either of them would show up while typing out the title of this question but apparently not.